# Flask RESTFUL OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, apache, rest, flask

I have a issue with my python flask-restful app. I am deploying my app on EC2 Amazon with apache but when I'am trying to connect to my api a "500 Internal Server Error" appears

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: employee
```

I don't understand since I use mysql connection and I test the connection  to my database with mysqlWorkBench

run.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from flask_restful.utils import cors
from src.resources.manageApp import addConfig, addBlueprints

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.decorators = [cors.crossdomain(origin='*', headers=['accept', 'Content-Type'])]

addConfig()
addBlueprints()
```

addConfig function

```
from src.common.app import app

app.config.from_object('src.common.config')
```

config.py

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True

ApiBaseUrl = '/api/'

ApiVersion = 'v1.1'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:password@db.domain.com:3306/clipse'

SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
```

api.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/clipse/Api/")

from deploy.run import app as application
application.config.from_object('src.common.config')
```

Database

[table employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apmHp.png)

Comment: Can you confirm your MySQL database has the employee table?

Comment: You could use [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) for example.

Comment: I edit my post thx for help

Comment: Are you setting `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` in your `run.py`?

Comment: SQLAlchemy has to be imported as well if this is not the case:
`from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx I solved my issue I use my main.py in api.wsgi for inport app your a right I'm not load the same instance

main.py

```
import sys
from src.resources.manageApp import addConfig, addBlueprints, app
from src.resources.db import db
from src.common import config

addConfig()
addBlueprints()

def main():
  ...
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

and my api.wsgi

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/api/")

from main import app as application
```

THX have a nice day :)